# ZAP API Scan failing with error Read timed out

Tags: bash, debian, zap

I am able to do an API scan as well as generate a report when I run the below command from Windows :

```
docker run -v "$(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw" -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py -t  http://10.170.170.170:1700 /account?field4=448808888888"&"field7=GENERIC01"&"field10=ABC076 -f openapi  -r ZAP_Report.htm
```

Once I switch to running the same command :

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py -t http://10.170.170.170:1700/account?field4=448808888888"&"field7=GENERIC01"&"field10=DCF43 -f openapi -r ~/serverkeys/ZAP_REPORT.htm
```

from Debian I get an error, not quite sure what I'm missing :

```
.....
[ZAP-ActiveScanner-1] WARN  org.zaproxy.zap.extension.ascanrules.CommandInjectionScanRule - Command Injection vulnerability check failed for parameter [field10] and payload [';cat /etc/passwd;'] due to an I/O error
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78) ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106) ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1153) ~[zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413) ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:2138) ~[zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.zaproxy.zap.ZapGetMethod.readResponse(ZapGetMethod.java:112) ~[zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1162) ~[zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:470) ~[zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:207) ~[zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397) ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.executeMethod(HttpSender.java:430) ~[zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.runMethod(HttpSender.java:672) ~[zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:627) ~[zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAuthenticated(HttpSender.java:602) ~[zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAuthenticated(HttpSender.java:585) ~[zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAndReceive(HttpSender.java:490) ~[zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.AbstractPlugin.sendAndReceive(AbstractPlugin.java:315) ~[zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.AbstractPlugin.sendAndReceive(AbstractPlugin.java:246) ~[zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.ascanrules.CommandInjectionScanRule.testCommandInjection(CommandInjectionScanRule.java:524) [ascanrules-release-42.zap:?]
        at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.ascanrules.CommandInjectionScanRule.scan(CommandInjectionScanRule.java:431) [ascanrules-release-42.zap:?]
        at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.AbstractAppParamPlugin.scan(AbstractAppParamPlugin.java:201) [zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.AbstractAppParamPlugin.scan(AbstractAppParamPlugin.java:126) [zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.AbstractAppParamPlugin.scan(AbstractAppParamPlugin.java:87) [zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.AbstractPlugin.run(AbstractPlugin.java:333) [zap-D-2021-10-25.jar:D-2021-10-25]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
493852 [Thread-6] INFO  org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess - completed host/plugin http://10.170.4.117:8002 | CommandInjectionScanRule in 421.201s with 84 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
493853 [Thread-6] INFO  org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess - start host http://10.170.170.170:1700 | DirectoryBrowsingScanRule strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
493988 [Thread-6] INFO  org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess - completed host/plugin http://10.170.170.170:1700 | DirectoryBrowsingScanRule in 0.136s with 2 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
493988 [Thread-6] INFO  org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess - start host http://10.170.170.170:1700 | BufferOverflowScanRule strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
494126 [Thread-6] INFO  org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess - completed host/plugin http://10.170.170.170:1700 | BufferOverflowScanRule in 0.137s with 3 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
494126 [Thread-6] INFO  org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess - start host http://10.170.170.170:1700 | FormatStringScanRule strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
494287 [Thread-6] INFO  org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess - completed host/plugin http://10.170.170.170:1700 | FormatStringScanRule in 0.161s with 9 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
494287 [Thread-6] INFO  org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess - start host http://10.170.170.170:1700 | CrlfInjectionScanRule strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
494560 [Thread-6] INFO  org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess - completed host/plugin http://10.170.170.170:1700 | CrlfInjectionScanRule in 0.273s with 21 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.

........
........
```

Is they any additional tracing I can do on the scan -  why its timing out?
It appears the scan is terminating before completing and its also pointing to /etc/passwd ??

Answer (score 0):

You are not necessarily missing anything.

ZAP typically makes loads of requests to the target. Some of those may timeout - thats all this warning is telling you. If you keep getting these then it might be an indication that your site has become unresponsive.